# Implementing a pool with fixed size of task list

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, threadpool

I want to create a simple simulation and I need to have a thread pool, so I decided to write one. My interface is as follows:

```
public interface ThreadPool {
    public void start();
    public int getTaskListSize();
    public void addTask(Task task);
    public Task getNextTask();
}
```

The most important part is that there the task list is limited in size, and when someone tries to add a task to it when it's full he is blocked and goes to wait on this object. With my implementation however threads that want to getNextTask wake up each other with notifyAll call, which is bad.

```
   @Override
    public void addTask(Task task) {
        synchronized (tasks) {
            tasks.add(task);
            log("task list size:" + tasks.size());
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Task getNextTask() {
        Task task;
        synchronized (tasks) {
            task = tasks.poll();
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }

        return task;
    }
```

Is there a clean way to fix this? I use ArrayBlockingQueue to hold tasks.

Call to addTask from a thread is:

```
protected void addTask(Task task, ThreadPool threadPool) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            log("trying to add " + task);
            threadPool.addTask(task);

            log("added " + task  +"!");
            return;
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            log("adding failed, waiting");
            synchronized(threadPool) {
                threadPool.wait()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering: why implementing something that already exists in the Java libraries? Did you study the corresponding classes and found them to be not what you need?
( just asking because: typically, the stuff that comes with Java is well-designed, and well-tested; so why spending time to re-invent the wheel?)

Comment: Because I want to learn how stuff works in depth.

Comment: ArrayBlockingQueue is thread-safe, and as its name indicates, it is blocking. No need to synchronize on it. Not sure why getNextTask() is public, and what the notifyAll calls are for. Also, why do you reinvent the wheel? Java has a thread pool implementation.

Comment: notifyAll are for threads that are in this threadpool, since they are outside of it. Indeed I don't have to synchronize on the array.

Comment: The thread which blocks on getNextTask() will automatically be notified by the blocking queue. notifyAll is useless. BTW, notifyAll is used towake up threads that are blocked in a wait() call on the same lock, and there isn't any in your code.

Comment: It isn't about getNextTask() but addNextTask(). When size of array is 10 and max size is 10, addNextTask throws IllegalStateException and then the thread that tried to add task uses wait() on ThreadPool.

Comment: "So I decided to write one": Wrong. In concurrency, never attempt the DIY unless you are an expert. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)